# html email send using copy paste from IE browser

Tags: php, internet-explorer, email, outlook

I have html which has to be sent though email.

When I send it through php using mail function, it looks good in gmail, outlook, yahoo etc.

But when i see that html in IE browser and copy paste into outlook and send the email then the mail does not render correct html which i get using php's mail.

Can I manage the same for copy past in outlook?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems copy-pasting text from one application to the next.

Usually I go through some other app to solve the problem: e.g. instead of copying text from IE to Outlook, you could try to copy the text from IE to Word or Notepad or whatever and from there to Outlook. Also you could try to use Firefox or Chrome and copy the text from there to Outlook.

I only have this problem with UTF-8 text, so you could also try to encode the HTML in another charset, if you are yourself the author of the HTML you copy.

Also, check for the default charset setting in Outlook. If you open a new (empty) email as, say, ISO-8859-1, and then copy text that was encodes as UTF-8, that might cause the problem.